# Google Push Notification Does Not Work In some Networks

Tags: android, networking, push-notification

I have an android application (not in the google play) and it is being used by a company (in their building) right now. It uses Google Push Notifications and actually notifications mean everything. Simply customers press buttons of our own developed device when they need someone and we send notifications to someone authorized.

So we developed and tested it and it works fine here in our network (our office wifi).
Then we tested it in thier network. it works fine, too. So they started to use it.

But sometimes it stops getting notifications (in customer's building) suddenly. In this case if we connect tablet to 3G then it starts again.

To Sum up,

Push notifications work fine when android device is connected my Office Wifi,

Push notifications work fine when android device is connected to 3G,

Push notifications does not work sometimes when android device is connected to our customer Wifi.

and idea will be really helpful thanks.

Comment: I think the firewall is blocking it, he needs to make some changes to his firewall settings

Comment: thanks. I will ask them. but it works then stops then works again under these conditions. can it be firewall still?

Answer (score 0):

Your customer WIFI needs some tuning. In order to work properly you need to open the following ports: 5228.5229.5230:

Check this out

`The device accesses the GCM servers on ports 5228-5230. If your organization has a firewall that restricts the traffic to or from the Internet, you'll need to configure it to allow connectivity with GCM. The ports to open are: 5228, 5229, and 5230. GCM typically only uses 5228, but it sometimes uses 5229 and 5230. GCM doesn't provide specific IPs. It changes IPs frequently. We recommend against using ACLs but if you must use them, take a broad approach such as the method suggested in this support link.`

Hope it helps

Comment: thank you very much. I will check this out and then correct your answer.